# How can I use the DiscretePlot and LogPlot?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, discrete

I am really new to mathematica and this will seem very basic, but the two last lines of the code do not work (the two prints work just fine), it gives me the error more input is needed(only for the DiscretePlot and LogPlot). The code is as follows:

```
iv1=a[0]==1;
iv2=a[1]==1;
rr=a[n]==a[n-1]+2*a[n-2];
sol=RSolve[{rr,iv1,iv2},a[n],n] // Simplify
a[n_]=a[n]/.sol[[1]];
Print[a[2],"   ",a[3],"   ",a[4],"   ",a[5]]
Print[a[50]]
DiscretePlot[a[n],{n,1,20}]
LogPlot[a[n],{n,1,20}]
```

Comment: Is this what you want?: `DiscretePlot[a[n], {n, 1, 20}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`

Comment: This is what I get (commenting out the `Print` statements): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4Wb.png . I don't get the error you describe.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought he wanted to plot log(a(n)) vs. n. I get different result from your discretePlot command. Is mine wrong?

Comment: @Nasser I was just looking into what might explain it...haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: I want to plot both graphs, the one with discrete and the one with log, but it gives me "Syntax
:Incomplete expression;more input is needed"

Comment: The syntax problem is not in the code you posted.  Try copying it and pasting it in a new cell in Mathematica.  -- You'll need to `Clear[a]` first, though!!

Comment: John, there can be hidden characters in the input cell sometimes.  Or sometimes you've entered a character that looks like a certain character but has a different character code.  That can lead to a syntax error.

Comment: @MichaelE2 oh yes ofcourse. thanks. I always forget this. That `ListLogPlot` takes the log itself. So I was taking the log of the log. I fixed it. I need to go make MORE coeffee now.

Comment: If it's a special character, you can search the documentation for that term.  There's also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowSpecialCharacters.html

Comment: @MichaelE2  I solved it produces the right graphs now, I think it was the problem with clear all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `LogPlot` on `a[n]` since `a[n]` only works on discrete values of its argument.

You could generate your own data and use `ListLogPlot`

```
data = Table[{n, a[n]}, {n, 1, 20}];
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All,  
        AxesLabel -> {"n", "log(a(n))"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I erased the last two lines from my code but it stills give me the same message:"Syntax
:Incomplete expression;more input is needed"

Comment: @JohnCarter The errors you get when you try to run your code again, due to redefinitions. Try to run the code each time from clean kernel, and you'll see you get no error. Each time you run the code, you need to do `ClearAll` before you run your code, due to how you wrote it.  Always start your code fragment you are trying with `ClearAll[...]` to avoid such problems.

Comment: As defined, `a[n]` "works" for non-integer values; however, the values are complex and do not display in a plot. The OP could use `Plot[Abs[a[n]], {n, 1, 20},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]` or `LogPlot[Abs[a[n]], {n, 1, 20}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon You are right actually. But I think the "spirit" of these is that they are meant to be used for integer only $n$. I assumed so, since it look like standard difference equation to me, but I did not check that they generated complex for non-discrete values.  But you do have a point there.

Comment: Difference equations are frequently extended to non-integer values similar to the way that factorial functions are extended to non-integer values. Look at `Fibonacci`